# Storing a list of floats or integers in Redis Search

Tags: python, search, redis

I'm testing Redis vector search solution. I have install the Redis server and have been following these tutorials and documentation:

1. https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/vector_databases/redis/getting-started-with-redis-and-openai.ipynb
2. https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/

Here is the index structure that I would like to create:

```py
id = NumericField(name="id")
user_id = NumericField(name="user_id")
title = TextField(name="title")
seo = NumericField(name="seo")
email = TextField(name="email")
tariff = NumericField(name="tariff")
cash = NumericField(name="cash")
title_embedding = VectorField("embeddings",
    "HNSW", {
        "TYPE": "FLOAT32",
        "DIM": VECTOR_DIM,
        "DISTANCE_METRIC": DISTANCE_METRIC,
        "INITIAL_CAP": VECTOR_NUMBER,
    }
)
rubrics = ???
```

It seems like there is a VERY limited number of data types supported by this "version" of Redis (*it's still not clear to me whether this vector based Redis is any different from a  regular Redis*).
So based on the [docs](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/basic-constructs/field-and-type-options/) *this* Redis supports only the following data types:

```
Number Fields, Geo Fields, Vector Fields, Tag Fields, Text Fields
```

How should I store a list of ints in *this* version of Redis?
I want to store a list of ints in the `rubrics` field, the list looks like this: `[1, 22, 33]`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use-case? Do you intend to use the list for querying or just to be included in the query results?

Comment: Regarding the other question - it’s not “vector based redis”, redisearch (or search and query) is an enhancement of the “vanilla” redis, and included in redis-stack from Redis Ltd.

Comment: @A.Guy Actually both, i would like to include the list in the results AFTER i have searched through it or applied some filtering. The original idea was to query RS just for vector similarity, get some scores and then send it to ES for filtering, aggregations, etc. But then I read that RS (and other vector databases) support not only similarity search but also standard operations (text search, filtering, aggs, etc), so I thought maybe we could ditch ES completely?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, depends on your exact use case.

If the numeric rubrics are used for some sort of tagging (for example, if a document has 1 it means something), you can use a TAG field for pre-filtering documents that has or doesn’t have some tags, and any union (OR) or intersection (AND) of tags.

You can also use the multi-value feature if your documents are stored in JSON objects. You’ll then be able to filter documents using a numeric range, and filter documents that have some value in their rubrics field in the query range.

You can also perform logic operations on your numeric ranges queries, and combine other conditions with other fields.

Links to useful documentation:
WILL ADD SOON